# is Emitting values from children components to ancestors can work

Tags: angular, angular5

I was reading about [passing data from children to parent components](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event), and I was wondering if we can use the same method to pass the data to the ancestor components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular events do not bubble across component boundaries. You have to reemit the events in all the components that the events passes through.